# Is there a way to buy bitcoin immediately?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I want to use PHP to write a script to buy bitcoins and my bitcoin balance will be updated immediately (i'm NOT in US).

For example, I use my credit cart to purchase bitcoins. less than 1 min later, I can see my new bitcoins in my address.

As I know, normally, it will take few hours / days to get bitcoin from some bitcoin sellers. It is not safe to get bitcoin immediately because banks allow charge back.

So is there a safe, automatic and immediate way to get / buy bitcoins?

Comment: You would need to pay for them by some method that's electronic, widely accepted, irreversible, and low-cost.  There aren't many such methods out there other than... Bitcoin.

Answer (score 2):

Coinbase offers instant buys, you need to enter your credit card info and go through the verification process, but it takes less than a minute to update my balance.  The max amount for instant buy/sell is 1000usd/day.

Comment: Hi @Th1nker, Thanks for your reply. But I am not in America

Comment: BTC-e also offers instant buy for their customers

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no such service. PayPal offers an API so payments can be detected automatically, but mostly nobody sells Bitcoin via PayPal because it's not worth the risk (chargebacks can happen months after the purchase, for example).

Comment: Moreover, I believe PayPal specifically forbids using their service to pay for cryptocoins.

Comment: How about DPS gateway? and are chargebacks only allowed after receiver approved?

Comment: @GarlicBread, I don't know in detail how it works. I'm just following recommendations I've heard on the forums. Maybe someone else can come with a more detailed answer.